# RewriteRule and Proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Two servers. example.net, and example.com

On http://example.net, My httpd.conf contains

```
# example.net
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^/felipetest2 http://example.com/webpage [P]
```

I am getting a 302 Moved, which is pointing to http://example.net/webpage, but should be http://example.com/webpage

What's going on?

I have control over both .net and .com servers in these examples.

I know I can do the same with ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse, but I'm trying to get my head around this one.

**Edit: Main Question: How do I show a maintenance page, without changing URL in the browser? On same domain, or across different domains?**

Comment: Is there any RewriteRule for `example.com`? Append a `[L]` flag to see what happens.

Comment: This is the only Rule

Answer (score 2):

You should use the flag [[R]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) instead of [[P]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) at the end of your RewriteRule if you would like that the redirection is performed externally by the browser.

Comment: Suppose I didn't want the visitor to 'notice' a change to the URL (i.e. the URL does not change) and no HTTP redirect is given....

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez if you want to do this you can only do this on the same domain, otherwise, even though you don't precise the [R] directive, Apache will generate a redirection.

Comment: This can only be done on the same domain? But `ProxyPass` can do this over more than one domain (I am using it myself, now). Why is `RewriteRule ...[P]` not able to do what `proxypass` can do? I thought that was the purpose of [P]